# How to get the type of the largest polygon inside a grid cell?

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

(1) I have a vector grid layer.

(2) I have a multipolygon layer. Each polygon has a specific type (in this case a vegatation type)

Now I want to get as an output the grid layer where each cell contains the type whose polygon (out of the vegetation - multipolygon layer) occupies the largest area.

Following figure shows the grid layer overlaping the multipolygon layer: 
[image: Multiploygon layer overlaping by grid layer]

Comment: Sorry to ask but ... do you mean you want to calculate the main vegetation type per grid cell ? Your question's title is clear ... but not the rest _imho_ ...

Comment: Yes, I want to get the main vegetation type per grid cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use QGIS **DB Manager** : Database / Database Manager / Database Manager then Virtual Layers / Qgis Layers.

Try a query like this one :

```
select grid.id,max(st_area(st_intersection(grid.geometry,vege.geometry))),vege.type
from vege, grid
where st_intersects(vege.geometry, grid.geometry)
group by grid.id
```

That should do the job ...

Adapt the query to your data structure if needed (columns namings) ...